# Is John saying that Christ is God and eternal?

Tags: exegesis, trinity, gospel-of-john

The Book of John says that God is the Word in the beginning.

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. *(John 1:1, NIV)*

How is Jesus Christ the son to the Word?

Jesus, when he was with the Twelve Apostles, told his disciples that no one was going to the Father except through him.

> Jesus answered, “I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me. If you really know me, you will know my Father as well. From now on, you do know him and have seen him.”
>
> Philip said, “Lord, show us the Father and that will be enough for us.”
>
> Jesus answered: “Don’t you know me, Philip, even after I have been among you such a long time? Anyone who has seen me has seen the Father. How can you say, ‘Show us the Father’? *(John 14:6-9, NIV)*

So, are these verses trying to say that Christ is God and that he has always been since the beginning, so Mary who came later bore Christ who was before?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE! You may want to take a look at [If God's nature includes being without origin, how is His Son, with an origin, equal to that nature?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/20452/4188) If I understand your question correctly, he's asking the same thing (so you already have answers).

Comment: If you do not find an acceptable answer there you should reword your question, and address exactly what you have difficulty with.

Comment: Since you do not scope your question within a specific denomination (as each denomination may have a similar but not the same response): consider asking this question here: [hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: YES. that's right, the word became flesh through birth.  But conceived by the Holy Spirit.  God is spirit.

Comment: I tried editing this, but it is still very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Question: “How is Jesus Christ the son to the Word?”

> John 1:1-17  In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God… All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made… He was in the world, and the world was made by him, and the world knew him not… But as many as received him, to them gave he power to become the sons of God, even to them that believe on his name… And the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us, (and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father,) full of grace and truth… And of his fulness have all we received, and grace for grace. For the law was given by Moses, but grace and truth came by Jesus Christ.

Jesus is not the Son of the Word; He is the Word that made all things.  He is the Word that the World knew not.  He is the Word that gave power to become the sons of God.  He is the Word that became flesh and dwelt amongst us.

Jesus Christ is the Eternally begotten of the Father, the manifest will of God the Father!

> John 5:37 And the Father himself, which hath sent me, hath borne witness of me. Ye have neither heard his voice at any time, nor seen his shape.
>
> John 14:7  If ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also: and from henceforth ye know him, and have seen him.
>
> John 14:9 Jesus saith unto him, Have I been so long time with you, and yet hast thou not known me, Philip? he that hath seen me hath seen the Father; and how sayest thou then, Shew us the Father?

Comment: Well put, Rick.  As for your natural follow-up question, user8625: does that mean that Jesus created the world?   YES